# Javascript. Canvas. Как закончить фигуру начатую в другом SWITCH CASE?

Tags: canvas, switch, case

По задумке, после первого клика мышью появляется первая точка вершины треугольника. После второго две точки должны соединиться отрезком.

```
var X, Y            // координаты каждого следующего нажатия мыши 
var triCount = 0    // сколько вершин треугольника уже отмечено

...

switch(triCount) {

// первый клик мышью
case 0:
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(X, Y, 1, 1);     // отмечаем первую вершину треугольника 
    ctx.stroke();             // делаем точку видимой
    triCount++;               // увеличиваем triCount до 1
    break;

// нажимаем кнопку мыши во второй раз получая X и Y для второй вершины
// попадаем в CASE1

case 1:             
    ctx.lineTo(X, Y);       // не рисует линию от предыдущей точки
    ctx.stroke();
    break;
}
```

Переход во второй CASE происходит корректно, проверял.
Переменные работают корректно: X и Y меняются после каждого клика мышки.
Если поставить весь код вместе внутри одного CASE, то рисует как нужно.
Пробовал без BRAKE (а вдруг?) - не помогает.
Пробовал closePath() во втором CASE - не помогает.

(дополнение)
Когда выписал этот код отдельно от остального скрипта все заработало, спасибо что предложили создать пример. Теперь знаю точно, что должно работать, буду искать ошибку в где-то другом месте. Вот рабочий пример:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>

<script>    
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

var triCount = 0;
var X = 0;
var Y = 0;

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);

function onMouseDown(e) { 

    X = e.offsetX;
    Y = e.offsetY;

    switch(triCount) {

        case 0:
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(X, Y, 1, 1);
            ctx.stroke();
            triCount++;
            break;

        case 1:             
            ctx.lineTo(X, Y);
            ctx.stroke();
            break;
        }
    }
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Все оказалось просто, при нажатии мыши, еще до SWITCH в скрипте стоял beginPath(). Таким образом, не закончив одной фигуры я начинал другую.

Comment: мало кода. Где создается `ctx`? Язык - javascript? Создайте работающий пример, используя кнопку редактора "Фрагмент кода на ..."

Comment: Когда выписал этот код отдельно от остального скрипта все заработало, спасибо что предложили создать пример. Теперь знаю что работать должно, буду искать ошибку в где-то другом месте.

Comment: Все оказалось просто, при нажатии мыши, еще до SWITCH в скрипте стоял beginPath(). Таким образом, не закончив одной фигуры я начинал другую.

Comment: Вы можете ниже ответить на Ваш вопрос сами, приведя ошибочный фрагмент кода и его исправление, и принять ответ как правильный. Я тоже за него проголосую.

Answer (score 1):

В моем полном коде, при нажатии мыши, еще до SWITCH, стояла команда beginPath(). Однако, когда среди прочих фигур, я добавил возможность рисовать треугольник, то не заметил, что этот beginPath() для треугольника недопустим, так как еще не добравшись до CASE1 он обозначает начало следующей фигуры. Таким образом терялась связь с точкой нарисованной в CASE0.

Фрагмент неверного кода:

```
function onMouseDown(e) {

    X = e.offsetX;
    Y = e.offsetY;

    ctx.beginPath();

    // рисование разных фигур в зависимости от значения ключа 'drawMethod' 
    draw();
```

Фрагмент верного кода:

```
 function onMouseDown(e) {

        X = e.offsetX;
        Y = e.offsetY;

        if(drawMethod !== 'triangle')
           ctx.beginPath();

        // рисование разных фигур в зависимости от значения ключа 'drawMethod' 
        draw();
```